# Magento 2 - WebApi /rest/V1/products/MY_SKU to create a new product error

Tags: product, magento-2.1, webapi

I'm having troubles to PUT a product using the WebApi of M2

Im using this JSON:

```
{
   "product": {
      "sku": "MY_SKU",
      "name": "My Product",
      "price": 20,
      "typeId": "simple",
      "status": 1,
      "visibility": 4,
      "attribute_set_id": "4",
      "extensionAttributes": {
         "stockItem": {
            "qty": 0,
            "isInStock": true
         }
      },
      "custom_attributes": [{
        "attribute_code": "url_key",
        "value": "myurlkey"
      }]
   }
}
```

But M2 gives an error:

```
{
  "message": "Unable to save product HERE2",
  "trace": "#0 /var/www/vhosts/example/example/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ProductRepository->save(Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Interceptor), false)\n#1 /var/www/vhosts/example/example/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ProductRepository\\Interceptor->___callParent('save', Array)\n#2 /var/www/vhosts/example/example/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\Chain\\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\\\Catalog...', 'save', Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ProductRepository\\Interceptor), Array, 'configurablePro...')\n#3 /var/www/vhosts/example/example/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Plugin/AroundProductRepositorySave.php(62): Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\Chain\\Chain->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\Chain\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Interceptor), false)\n#4 /var/www/vhosts/example/example/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\\ConfigurableProduct\\Model\\Plugin\\AroundProductRepositorySave->aroundSave(Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ProductRepository\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Interceptor), false)\n#5 /var/www/vhosts/example/example/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\Chain\\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\\\Catalog...', 'save', Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ProductRepository\\Interceptor), Array, 'catalogInventor...')\n#6 /var/www/vhosts/example/example/vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/Plugin/AroundProductRepositorySave.php(74): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ProductRepository\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Interceptor), false)\n#7 /var/www/vhosts/example/example/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\\CatalogInventory\\Model\\Plugin\\AroundProductRepositorySave->aroundSave(Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ProductRepository\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Interceptor), false)\n#8 /var/www/vhosts/example/example/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Model/ProductRepository/Interceptor.php(52): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ProductRepository\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save', Array, Array)\n#9 [internal function]: Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ProductRepository\\Interceptor->save(Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Interceptor), false)\n#10 /var/www/vhosts/example/example/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(307): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#11 /var/www/vhosts/example/example/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(216): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->processApiRequest()\n#12 /var/www/vhosts/example/example/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#13 /var/www/vhosts/example/example/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#14 /var/www/vhosts/example/example/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#15 /var/www/vhosts/example/example/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http))\n#16 {main}"
}
```

Looking at `Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository` at line 488 in Magento 2.1.1

```
try {
            if ($tierPrices !== null) {
                $product->setData('tier_price', $tierPrices);
            }
            unset($this->instances[$product->getSku()]);
            unset($this->instancesById[$product->getId()]);
            $this->resourceModel->save($product);
        } catch (\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Exception $exception) {
            throw \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException::invalidFieldValue(
                $exception->getAttributeCode(),
                $product->getData($exception->getAttributeCode()),
                $exception
            );
        } catch (ValidatorException $e) {
            throw new CouldNotSaveException(__($e->getMessage()));
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            throw $e;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException(__('Unable to save product HERE2'));
        }
        unset($this->instances[$product->getSku()]);
        unset($this->instancesById[$product->getId()]);
        return $this->get($product->getSku());
```

It just fails at saving the data in the model and the JSON is fine

So, what could be happening? Could be a required attribute? The WS needs more data to be able to create the product?

Comment: Try to modify the exception message `Unable to save product HERE2` with `$e->getMessage()` and tell us what you get

Comment: Wow....... I See... `General error: 1449 The user specified as a definer ('Ubuntu01'@'%') does not exist, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `type_id`, `sku`, `has_options`, `required_options`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` I copy the entire site  from dev to preprod... so i guessing it has something to do with the database user

Comment: Yeah that sounds definitely like this is a database credentials issue

Answer (score 0):

Magento creates all these triggers with its definer as the initial instalattion database user

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_category_entity_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `catalog_category_entity`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_category_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_category_entity_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `catalog_category_entity`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_category_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_category_product_after_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `catalog_category_product`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`product_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_category_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`product_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_category_product_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `catalog_category_product`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_category_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_category_entity_int_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `catalog_category_entity_int`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_category_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_category_product_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `catalog_category_product`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_category_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_category_entity_int_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `catalog_category_entity_int`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_category_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_bundle_selection_after_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `catalog_product_bundle_selection`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`parent_product_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_bundle_selection_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `catalog_product_bundle_selection`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`parent_product_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_bundle_selection_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `catalog_product_bundle_selection`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`parent_product_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `catalog_product_entity`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_after_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `catalog_product_entity`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_category_entity_int_after_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `catalog_category_entity_int`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_category_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_datetime_after_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `catalog_product_entity_datetime`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `catalog_product_entity`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_datetime_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `catalog_product_entity_datetime`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_datetime_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `catalog_product_entity_datetime`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_decimal_after_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `catalog_product_entity_decimal`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_attribute_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_decimal_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `catalog_product_entity_decimal`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_attribute_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_gallery_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `catalog_product_entity_gallery`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_gallery_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `catalog_product_entity_gallery`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_decimal_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `catalog_product_entity_decimal`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_attribute_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_gallery_after_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `catalog_product_entity_gallery`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_int_after_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `catalog_product_entity_int`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_category_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_attribute_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_int_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `catalog_product_entity_int`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_category_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_attribute_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_after_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`value_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_int_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `catalog_product_entity_int`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_category_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_attribute_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`value_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_after_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_text_after_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `catalog_product_entity_text`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_text_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `catalog_product_entity_text`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_tier_price_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`value_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_text_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `catalog_product_entity_text`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_varchar_after_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `catalog_product_entity_varchar`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_attribute_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_varchar_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `catalog_product_entity_varchar`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_attribute_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_tier_price_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_link_after_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `catalog_product_link`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`product_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_link_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `catalog_product_link`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_super_link_after_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `catalog_product_super_link`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`product_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_tier_price_after_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_entity_varchar_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `catalog_product_entity_varchar`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_attribute_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_link_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `catalog_product_link`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_super_link_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `catalog_product_super_link`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_super_link_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `catalog_product_super_link`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_website_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `catalog_product_website`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_category_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_website_after_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `catalog_product_website`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`product_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_category_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`product_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_cataloginventory_stock_item_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `cataloginventory_stock_item`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `cataloginventory_stock_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_cataloginventory_stock_item_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `cataloginventory_stock_item`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `cataloginventory_stock_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_product_website_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `catalog_product_website`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_category_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_cataloginventory_stock_item_after_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `cataloginventory_stock_item`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`product_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `cataloginventory_stock_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`product_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalogrule_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `catalogrule`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_rule_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`rule_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalog_category_entity_after_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `catalog_category_entity`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_category_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalogrule_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `catalogrule`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_rule_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`rule_id`);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_catalogrule_after_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `catalogrule`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_rule_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`rule_id`);
END
```

Problem was that i dumped the sql file from dev to preprod, just as is, so when imported the sql file in the preprod database, all these's triggers definer user was a different one.. I mean, in DEV the database user when installing Magento was Ubunt01 while in preprod i just create a new database with user Example and then dumped the sql file from dev